# How to open gmail inbox from android app?

Tags: android

I want to know how to open android gmail inbox programatically?

Can anybody help me on this?

Thanks
Monali

Comment: And I want BMW! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am poor I am just want satisfied with polo

Answer (score 4):

There is no documented and supported `Intent` to open the Gmail inbox. There might not even *be* a Gmail inbox on any given device, either because the app is not there or because the user is not using it.